# When I start an ionic project it demands a proxy protocol:

Tags: ionic-framework

```
$ ionic -v
6.20.9

Adminn@DESKTOP-VSHVHNU MINGW64 ~
$ ionic start proj1 blank
√ Preparing directory .\proj1 in 11.05ms
TypeError: You must specify a "protocol" for the proxy type (http, https, socks, socks4, socks4a, socks5, socks5h, pac+data, pac+file, pac+ftp, pac+http, pac+https)

at mapOptsToProxy (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:100:11)
at new ProxyAgent (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:150:17)
at ProxyAgent (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:145:45)
at Request.proxy (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\superagent-proxy\index.js:71:15)
at createRequest (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\utils\http.js:33:17)
at async StartCommand.downloadStarterTemplate (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\commands\start.js:674:25)
at async StartCommand.run (C:\Users\Adminn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\commands\start.js:469:13)
```

I tried to start a new ionic project, but it demands a proxy `URL`. I really can't get it.